# Upgrade SonarQube from version 5.6.4 to 6.7.2

Tags: sonarqube

I want to upgrade SonarQube and I haven't done this before so I have few question. Please could you help me with them?

1. How can I find which edition is installed on my server?
2. How can I find if the installed version is licensed or not?
3. How can I upgrade from 5.6.4 to  6.7 LTS? Do you have upgrade guide for the same?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and narrow your post to _one_ question. (You seem to already know the answer to #1, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

You can always find which version is installed by logging into the SonarQube web app and looking at the footer of the page or by going to Administration / System / System Info. If you for some reason can't log in to the web app, and installation folder name does not contain the version number as it does by default, look in the "lib" folder for a file that looks like "sonar-application-6.3.1.jar". That will tell you the version number as well.

Here are the general steps for upgrading, from the [Upgrade the Server docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrading/):

> 1. Download and unzip the SonarQube distribution of your edition in a
>      fresh directory, let's say $NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME
> 2. Manually install the
>      non-default plugins that are compatible with your version of
>      SonarQube. Use the Compatibility Matrix to ensure that the versions
>      you install are compatible with your server version. Note that the
>      most recent versions of all SonarSource code analyzers available in
>      your edition are installed by default. Simply copying plugins from
>      the old server to the new is not recommended; incompatible or
>      duplicate plugins could cause startup errors.
> 3. Update the contents of
>      sonar.properties and wrapper.conf files (in
>      $NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/conf) with the settings of the related files in
>      the $OLD_SONARQUBE_HOME/conf directory (web server URL, database,
>      ldap settings, etc.). Do not copy-paste the old files. If you are
>      using the Oracle DB, copy its JDBC driver into
>      $NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle
> 4. Stop your old
>      SonarQube Server
> 5. Start your new SonarQube Server
> 6. Browse to
>      http://yourSonarQubeServerURL/setup and follow the setup
>      instructions
> 7. Analyze your projects (and compute your
>      Views|Portofolios|Application if you own the Enterprise Edition
>      product) to get fresh data

Before embarking on this, you will want to check out the intermediate upgrade notes for each version in order: [6.0](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.0+Upgrade+Notes), [6.1](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.1+Upgrade+Notes), [6.2](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.2+Upgrade+Notes), [6.3](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.3+Upgrade+Notes), [6.4](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.4+Upgrade+Notes), [6.5](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.5+Upgrade+Notes), [6.6](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.6+Upgrade+Notes), and [6.7](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.7+Upgrade+Notes).

Note that upgrade notes for versions after 6.7 are hosted at the [new documentation site](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrade-notes/).